# Scraping tabbed table from AWS pricing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to builder scraper to scrape tabs which are tables in this page (https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) I am only interested in the data thats `training`, `processing` and few others.

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content)
tables = soup.find_all("table")

inst_table = str(tables[0])
```

But it looks like I have to use some sort of a dynamic mechanism to get the tabbed switch.

Assume we clicked on training tab, My goal is to build a file that stores scraped data

```
  "ml.t2.medium": {
    "vCPU": 2.0,
    "mem_GiB": 4.0,
    "price": 0.15,
    "category": "Standard",
    "task": "training",
  }
```

Comment: In which step do you want to involve Selenium?

Comment: //li[contains(@class,'lb-tabs-trigger')]//div[contains(text(),'Training')] would work for an xpath for the clicking of the training element.

Comment: @DebanjanB basically I want to start from the main page and then carry out the rest of the scraping dynamically not sure how to do it. I haven't really done much selenium.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan do i need to use selenium? Can you provide an example.

Comment: @add-semi-colons Where can I find these `ml.t2.medium`, `"vCPU": 2.0`, `"category": "Standard"`, `"task": "training"` data?

Comment: @DebanjanB so if you click `training` the table column headers has the values `Standard Instances vCPU Memory Price per Hour` but scrape the data and then organize into the structure that i pasted above.

Comment: @add-semi-colons The headers are _Hours Training Instance Debug Instance Cost per hour  Sub-total_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is you don't need the heavy guns of `selenium`.

As with AWS, there's almost alwyas an API you can query that returns the data you want.

Here's what you need and how to get it:

```py
import json
import time

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0",
}

endpoint = f"https://b0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/2.0/meteredUnitMaps/" \
           f"sagemaker/USD/current/sagemaker-instances.json?" \
           f"timestamp={int(time.time())}"
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()

for region, region_data in response["regions"].items():
    if region == "EU (Frankfurt)":
        for instance_type, instance_data in region_data.items():
            print(json.dumps(instance_data, indent=2))
```

Sample output for `EU (Frankfurt)` (shortened for brevity):

```
{
  "rateCode": "X7Z5CZBN2ZY5QED6.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
  "price": "6.1120000000",
  "Instance": "ml.g4dn.12xlarge",
  "Clock Speed": "2.5 GHz",
  "Instance Type": "ml.g4dn.12xlarge-AsyncInf",
  "Component": "AsyncInf",
  "VCPU": "48",
  "Memory": "192 GiB"
}
{
  "rateCode": "F926HEYB3SV5TQ3Y.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
  "price": "6.8000000000",
  "Instance": "ml.g4dn.16xlarge",
  "Clock Speed": "2.5 GHz",
  "Instance Type": "ml.g4dn.16xlarge-AsyncInf",
  "Component": "AsyncInf",
  "VCPU": "64",
  "Memory": "256 GiB"
}
{
  "rateCode": "7SMSS7DTJHR8UWN7.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
  "price": "1.8810000000",
  "Instance": "ml.g4dn.4xlarge",
  "Clock Speed": "2.5 GHz",
  "Instance Type": "ml.g4dn.4xlarge-AsyncInf",
  "Component": "AsyncInf",
  "VCPU": "16",
  "Memory": "64 GiB"
}

and much more ...
```